# How to CTRL SHIFT ENTER on VBA Formula

Tags: excel, vba

It's supposed to be an array formula, so that's why I try to insert {} there. but i encountered an error when i run it.

Here is my code:

```
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow > 1 Then

     Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C" & lastrow).Value = _
          "=CONCATENATE(MIN(IF(B3:B251=B3,A3:A251)),""-"",MAX(IF(B3:B251=B3,A3:A251)))"

End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `.Value` for `.FormulaArray` like this:

```
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If lastrow > 1 Then


Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C" & lastrow).FormulaArray = _
     "=CONCATENATE(MIN(IF(B3:B251=B3,A3:A251)),""-"",MAX(IF(B3:B251=B3,A3:A251)))"

End If
```

Then you can use the {}

For the usual formulas you can use `.Formula` or  `.FormulaR1C1` for the ones with relative notation.

Comment: @coder consider to mark this as the answer so others may find it easier :)